# Trying to run typeWriter.js embedded without success

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get [this script](https://www.cssscript.com/pure-javascript-typewriter-typing-effect-typewriter-js/) to run.  It's intended to be run as a reference to an external script file, but I need the script to be embedded for reasons that are not worth going into.  I think I've done it correctly, but obviously not since when I load the file the text appears all at one.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

```
<html>
    <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoad", typeWriter, false);
    var typeWriter = function (selector, type, interval) {
        "use strict";
        var el = document.querySelectorAll(selector), // Getting elements in the DOM
            i = 0,
            len = el.length, // Length of element on the page
            list = [], // List of elements on the page in the DOM
            a,
            all,
            text,
            start,
            end,
            nextText,
            style,
            clear;
        for (; i < len; i++) {
            list.push(el[i]); // Pushing the element in the list array
        }
        for (a in list) {
            all = list[a]; // List of all element
            text = all.innerHTML += " <span id='cursor'>|</span>"; // InnerHTML of the elements 
            start = 0; // Start index of the text in the elements 
            end = 0; // End index of the text in the elements
            style = document.createElement("style");
            document.head.appendChild(style);
            //Setting the default interval to 100 when interval is not set by the user
            if (typeof interval === "undefined") {
                interval = 100;
            }
            if (arguments[1] === "true") {
                clear = setInterval(function () { // Animation start
                    var newText = text.substr(start, end);
                    all.innerHTML = newText += " <span id='cursor'>|</span>";
                    end = end + 1; //loops through the text in the element
                    // Insert stylesheet to the document to animate cursor 
                    style.sheet.insertRule("@-webkit-keyframes cursor {0% { opacity : 1;}100% { opacity : 0;}}", 0);
                    style.sheet.insertRule("@keyframes cursor {0% { opacity : 1;}100% { opacity : 0;}}", 0);
                    cursor.style.fontSize = "30px";
                    cursor.style.fontWeight = "bold";
                    cursor.style.webkitAnimation = "cursor 0.5s infinite";
                    cursor.style.animation = "cursor 0.5s infinite";
                    if (newText === text) {
                        clearInterval(clear); // Animation end
                    }
                }, interval);
            }
            return all;
        }
    };
    typeWriter("#para1","true",100);
</script>
<p id="para1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer to this.  The problem is that I put the function call before #para1.  Putting it after makes the function work.